# How to convert path with default share [\\{host}\c$\...] to default path [c:\...]

Tags: c#, path, shared-directory

How to convert a path defined through a default share of remote host like

```
\\{host}\c$\SomeFolder\SomeDeeperFolder
```

into a local path notation like:

```
c:\SomeFolder\SomeDeeperFolder
```

I can try splitting the original path and get the host or drive agnostic path and then concat with `C:\` like follows, but I seek for **a kind of built-in class/method** to achieve that conversion *neatlier*:

```
var defaultSharedPath = "\\\\someremotehostname\\c$\\SomeFolder\\SomeDeeperFolder";
// The drive is always c:\ in my case, so I can directly split with it
var path = defaultSharedPath.Split(new string[] { "\\c$\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList().Last();
var localLikePath = "C:\\" + path;

Console.WriteLine(localLikePath);
```

Comment: I would have splited by single '\' and the add the `c:\`

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way without regular string operations like split&concat. I'd rather utilize the `URI` class of C# or so...